# onSuccessListener for storing SQLite Data

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, firebase

As in firebase there is an onsuccesslistener for adding data so that you can perform something is the task is successful. Is there someway to know that for storing data in sqlite too?

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                        contentValues.put(KEY_SENDER, "Other");

long returnVariable11 = db11.insert(TABLE_CHAT_DATA, null, contentValues);
           if (returnVariable11 == -1) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
```

This particular code is insdide the firebaserecycleradapter so if the adapter is listening this data keeps on adding multiple times. So i thought i could stop if by adding a onSuccessListener so that it stops after adding once but i'm not sure on how to do that. So can anyone suggest what i could do that prevent it from adding data to sqlite again and again?

Comment: can add the firebase code you are using

Answer (score 0):

You could use `try{} catch{}` block and handle your transaction with listener

Comment: How exactly? Sorry stilll an amateur

Comment: @LaylaMcKenzy [this](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.database.sqlite.SQLiteTransactionListener) may help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the listener by using `adapter.stopListening()` after adding the first row to local db.

Comment: The thing is i dont want to call stop listening as new data will be added to the table. i just want to stop adding same data

Comment: compare between local saved data and the received one, Create a method to read from database and compare the returned data with the one from populateViewHolder method